# How to Link newly inserted row with Foreign Key?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, foreign-key

In my database I have 2 tables linked together with a foreign key relationship.

Parent Table = controls.slot_table

Child Table = controls.IO_table

When a new row is inserted into the parent table (A), I would like to insert a row into table B and link it via foreign key to the new row in table A.

My rough draft looks like this (I know it has syntax errors, but this is the idea):

```
CREATE TRIGGER controls.Test_Insert_Linked_Row ON controls.slot_table AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO controls.IO_table
    (
        point_description_A,
        PLC_slot_ID

    )
    VALUES
    (
        'Test Automatically Generated Line',
        t1.ID_auto
    )

    FROM controls.slot_table as t1
    LEFT JOIN inserted as i

END
GO
```

Comment: I guess you meant `...VALUES
    (
        'Test Automatically Generated Line',
        inserted.ID_auto
    )`

Comment: @mustaccio I appreciate the suggestion, but your code using `inserted.ID_auto` causes the error "multi-part identifier could not be bound".

Comment: Well, I just used your pseudo-syntax to show what needs to change _in your example_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers run for each statement, so you need INSERT ... SELECT not INSERT ... VALUES.  And there's no need to join the target table; INSERTED has everything you need.

```
INSERT INTO controls.IO_table(point_description_A, PLC_slot_ID)
SELECT 'Test Automatically Generated Line', i.ID_auto
FROM inserted  i
```